# How do you eliminate white background from a vector eps image

Tags: vector, background, eps

My vector eps that I purchased has a white background that I don't want when I bring it into InDesign. I do not want to change it to a jpeg because I want to be able to enlarge the image quite a bit and keep the quality.

Comment: It depends upon how the image is constructed. You may be able to merely open the EPS and delete the white object. Or.. it may take more work if the background has been integrated into the artwork. Basically, you need to confirm the white isn't *actually* part of the EPS, and if it is, remove it. You need to open the EPS in a vector editor - Illustrator or Inkscape - and check.

Comment: When I open the vector eps in illustrator, I can click and highlight the illustration and see the outlined shapes, so I don't think the background is part of the vector. But still, when I bring it into InDesign, the white remains as a rectangle shape behind it.

Comment: If there's no actual background, then save the image as an AI file from Illustrator. Then import that AI file into InDesign.

Comment: Then I'd merely resave the file as an .ai file and use that. Some apps have  options when saving an EPS to add a background. So, you'll probably just need to resave it.. and because you are using InDesign, you may as well save it as an .ai file. Use `Save As`.

Comment: And will that ai file still be able to enlarge without losing quality? Will it retain that ability of a vector?

Comment: Yes the .ai file will be just as good as the .eps. In fact, in some ways better.

Comment: Thanks very much! It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to verify the white isn't *actually* part of the artwork. To do this you need to **open** the EPS in a **vector editor** - Illustrator or Inkscape. Then check the construction.

If there's a white object for the background, merely remove it and resave the file.

If there is no white object for the background... Some applications, when saving an EPS, have options to add a background. So, to overcome that, you merely need to resave the file.

Because you are using Indesign, I would open and resave the file (using `Save As`) as an **.ai file**.

The .ai file will still be vector if the eps was vector. The artwork won't change in any way. What does change is the "wrapper" the artwork is contained in. EPS is merely a file wrapper and like all wrappers has some limitations. Because you are using InDesign, using the .ai format will actually provide you with a bit *more* options when importing the artwork. And if the background was part of the "EPS wrapper", the resaving will remove that background.

Answer (score 0):

I'm literally doing that right now with some stock images. Open in Illustrator, remove the white box behind them, save and close.